# How do I check if a 2-track WAV file is "really" in stereo?

Tags: linux, audio, duplicate, wav, stereo

I have an audio file (WAV format to be specific). When I open it with an editor (e.g. audacity), I see two channels I suspect that the recording is actually mono rather than audio, i.e. I suspect the tracks are duplicate. What's an easy way to check whether they are...

- "perfectly" duplicate?
- "nearly" duplicate, undistinguishable to the ear?

I'm using Devuan GNU/Linux. A command-line solution would be nice, GUI is ok too.

Answer (score 96):

This answer has now been expanded to cover three different way of achieving this, from the simplest; no code required, just listen, to more complex examples that could be used for bulk testing.

#### Simplest method

**Flip the phase of one side & sum the outputs to mono.**
If the result is silence, then it was mono; if not, it was stereo.
Even in stereo some parts will have been panned centre - vocals, bass, a lot of the drums etc, but you will hear an overwhelming difference between "some bits are missing " and "almost total silence".
If you just hear odd little tinny, crackly bits of the track, or just periodic fizzes, crackles & thumps, put this down to poor encoding, it's still 'mono' to all intents & purposes.

This relies on the physics of sound; in its simplest form if you add two identical waveforms together, the result will be twice as loud. If you invert one, then they will cancel each other out & always add up to 'zero'… silence. This principle is used for such as noise-cancelling headphones & background noise reduction in your phone's microphone.

**Method**
From the [Audacity manual](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/invert.html)…

> Effect > Invert
> There is no effect dialog containing parameters for this effect; Invert operates directly on the selected audio.
> If the inversion takes an appreciable time, a progress dialog will appear.
>
> Usage Examples
>
> Use the Audio Track Dropdown Menu and choose Split Stereo to Mono.
> Select one channel but not the other, apply Invert and then Play. The vocals in each track will cancel each other out, leaving just the instrumentals.
> Find out how different the stereo channels are: Use the same steps 1 and 2 above on any stereo track. If the audio is just as loud after the steps as before, the channels are very different. If the result is silence, the track is not really stereo but dual mono, where both left and right contain completely identical audio.

#### Simple method

Load (import) the (allegedly stereo) file in Audacity. From the top bar menu select *Effect*, *Nyquist Prompt…*. Paste the following:

```
(diff (aref *track* 0) (aref *track* 1))
```

and hit OK. This will compute the difference between the two tracks.

- Completely silent result means the tracks were identical.
- Very quiet or very noisy result means the tracks were almost identical.
- A result that resembles the original audio at least for some fragment(s) means the tracks were *probably* different.

"Probably", because it may happen the tracks were identical but opposite in phase. Then `diff` will increase the amplitude instead of bringing it to zero. The result will be significantly louder than the original. To rule this possibility out get back to the original tracks (*Edit*, *Undo Nyquist Prompt*) and `sum` instead of computing the `diff`:

```
(sum (aref *track* 0) (aref *track* 1))
```

Completely silent result means the tracks were identical but opposite in phase.

These simple tests will fail if the two tracks are similar but shifted in phase, or similar but with different volumes. A formula able to spot similarities also in such cases may exist but I'm not familiar with the [Audacity Nyquist Prompt](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/invert.html) enough to help you further.

This answer took a lot from the following Audacity Forum thread: [Arithmetic track mix operations](https://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?t=109755).

---

#### Not so simple method

Use the following code to create a `.png` graphics from your `.wav`. It runs `ffmpeg` and `convert` (from Imagemagick).

```sh
#!/bin/sh

for input do

ffmpeg -nostdin -i "$input" -lavfi \
 '[0:a] channelsplit=channel_layout=stereo [left][right];
  [left] loudnorm [L];
  [right] loudnorm [R];
  [L][R] join=inputs=2:channel_layout=stereo [a];
  [a] showspectrumpic=s=800x600:mode=combined:color=channel:legend=no [out]' \
  -f apng -map '[out]' - \
| convert - -colorspace RGB -color-matrix \
' 20   0 -20   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0  20 -20   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0
' "$input".png

done
```

Name it `spect` and make executable (`chmod +x spect`). Provide one or more allegedly stereo `.wav` files as command line arguments. Example:

```
./spect foo.wav /path/to/bar.wav
```

This will generate `foo.wav.png` and `/path/to/bar.wav.png`. By examining these files you will be able to tell if the input files were really in stereo.

What the script does:

1. (`ffmpeg`) It normalizes left and right channels independently. This is in case a fake stereo file was created by duplicating mono with different amplification.
2. (still `ffmpeg`) It visualizes the spectrum as graphics, where the two channels are represented by different colors. This makes the method immune to phase shifts because it's amplitude what matters when creating a spectrum like this, not phase. Red and green components correspond to the two channels; blue component encodes what's common to the two channels (it will be useful in a moment).
3. (`convert`) It processes the graphics:

   - "Left" and "right" color components are reduced by the "common" component. This way we emphasize fragments where the two channels differ.
   - The result is enhanced by the factor of 20 (you can tweak this).
   - Colors are remapped from red/green to red/blue. This is only because I wanted the solution to be more colorblind-friendly.

I will analyze some example results down below. From it you can learn how to tell if stereo is genuine.

Notes:

- The code assumes there are two channels. It was only tested with `.wav` files having two channels.
- In the pictures time flows from left to right, frequency rises from bottom to top.
- You may want not to normalize. In this case `showspectrumpic` is the only filter you need in `ffmpeg`.
- I used `800x600` in this answer. Adjust the resolution to your needs.
- The top half in each picture is black, I guess it spans to 48 kHz (?) while 22.1 kHz would be enough. My `ffmpeg` seems not to support the `stop` option for [`showspectrumpic`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#showspectrumpic), most likely this option would help. There are other methods to deal with this "issue" but I decided not to obfuscate the code. It's an inconvenience, not really an issue.
- `spect` can be used with `find -exec` or `find | xargs`.
- Further automatic processing is possible, ultimately to a point where the script tells you `I'm X% certain it's genuine stereo, I'm Y% certain it's fake stereo`. In this answer I won't go this far. Look at pictures and apply heuristics. Learn from the examples below.

---

#### Examples – song 1

This is the original `.wav` of song 1 processed by `spect`:

[image: song 1, genuine stereo]

You can see there are columns of red, columns of blue. This is where (when) one of the channels dominates. This indicates it's genuine stereo.

> Queen – Bohemian Rhapsody

---

The same song 1 with one channel opposite in phase looks virtually identical (click to enlarge):

[image: song 1, genuine stereo, opposite phase in one channel]

---

The same song 1 mixed to mono and presented as stereo (two identical channels), fake stereo:

[image: song 1, fake stereo]

The result is virtually all black. In theory it should be perfectly black. TBH I don't know where exactly the artifacts come from. The important thing is there is no detailed "structure" the original song had. The `diff` method from way above would generate silence for this one.

---

The same song 1 mixed to mono and presented as stereo (two identical channels), fake stereo, but with one channel opposite in phase:

[image: song 1, fake stereo, opposite phase in one channel]

This one would "fool" the `diff` method, you would need the `sum` method. `spect` works well regardless.

---

The same song 1 mixed to mono and presented as stereo, fake stereo, but with one channel reduced in volume by 10 dB:

[image: song 1, fake stereo, one channel reduced volume]

You can see artifacts but again the picture looks very different than the one of the original song. Neither `diff` nor `sum` would generate silence.

---

The same song 1 mixed to mono and presented as stereo, fake stereo, but with one channel reduced in volume by 10 dB and opposite in phase:

[image: song 1, fake stereo, one channel reduced volume]

It should now be clear opposite phase doesn't matter to `spect`. The rest of this answer treats this issue as solved.

---

For comparison: original song 1 with one channel reduced in volume by 10 dB:

[image: song 1, genuine stereo, one channel reduced volume]

Thanks to normalizing channels separately, the detailed "structure" the original song had is still visible.

---

The same song 1 with one channel completely silent:

[image: song 1, one channel silent]

---

The above results one next to the other. From left to right:

- **genuine stereo**
- **genuine stereo**, unbalanced
- one channel silent
- fake stereo
- fake stereo, unbalanced

<kbd>[image: song 1, genuine stereo]</kbd> <kbd>[image: song 1, genuine stereo, one channel unbalanced]</kbd> [image: song 1, one channel silent] [image: song 1, fake stereo] [image: song 1, fake stereo, one channel unbalanced]

Notes:

- If I manipulated the other channel, the blue or red artifacts might be of the other color. Details matter, not the color.
- "Genuine stereo, unbalanced" is still genuine stereo. "Unbalanced" means one channel is not as loud as the other. Here I manipulated the original file to achieve this. In general it may be the original recording was like this. It does not mean somebody tampered with the file.

---

#### Examples – song 2

This is the original `.wav` of song 1 processed by `spect`:

[image: song 1, genuine stereo]

This song does not separate channels as clearly as the first one, there are no columns of red or blue. Still some frequencies are more red than blue. The characteristics changes few times as the song goes. This indicates it's genuine stereo.

> Counting Crows – Mr. Jones

---

Different results one next to the other. From left to right:

- **genuine stereo**
- **genuine stereo**, unbalanced
- one channel silent
- fake stereo
- fake stereo, unbalanced

<kbd>[image: song 2, genuine stereo]</kbd> <kbd>[image: song 2, genuine stereo, unbalanced]</kbd> [image: song 2, one channel silent] [image: song 2, fake stereo] [image: song 2, fake stereo, unbalanced]

Like for the song 1, you can tell genuine stereo by spotting detailed "structure".

---

#### Examples – song 3

This song is in fact monophonic. Mono signal had been recorded to (I suspect) a stereo tape. Ripped as stereo from the tape along with tape noise different for each channel.

[image: song 3]

There is no detailed "structure", just noise. This indicates the difference between the channels is basically just noise. The result form the `diff` method would not be silent, although for this exact `.wav` file the method would work because I could play the result and hear it's noise.

With unbalanced input the `diff`/`sum` method may work if you normalize first. Our `spect` does this automatically. For the record, this is how unbalanced song 3 processed by `spect` looks like:

[image: song 3, unbalanced]

---

#### Final notes

- Long `.wav` "compressed" to `.png` where 800 pixels cover the entire duration may look like noise. A reasonable approach is to improve `spect` so it retrieves the duration beforehand and adjusts the horizontal resolution accordingly.
- If your input *is* noise then the output from `spect` will be noise. You may still be able to tell something from the intensity of it, but since the method bases on spotting detailed "structure", it will not give you as obvious results as in cases of genuine stereo for our example songs 1 and 2.
- Experiment. :)

Comment: @einpoklum In theory: destructive interference when you are equally distant from both speakers. But your head is not a point, in practice it's probably hard to tell. With headphones you may not hear any obvious difference at all. I tested with headphones: opposite phases sound somewhat strange in comparison to identical tracks. But non-identical tracks may sound similar. Notes: (1) I'm not a musician nor a sound expert; (2) my current headphones are dumb and work like speakers (my "good Bluetooth headphones" mentioned in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1119386/432690) no longer work).

Comment: @einpoklum When I was working with professional sound equipment, we had a button to reverse the phase of the subwoofers with respect to the rest of the sound.  While we could never quite work out the physics of why it mattered, we did notice that one setting sounded better than the other, but which one sounded better was venue dependent.  The human ear is an amazing signal processing device that does lots of things that can seem really strange!

Comment: @einpoklum My rear speakers have two tweeters and a switch to toggle between single tweeter, dual in phase tweeter and dual counter phase tweeters. The effects are quite interesting. Dual counter phase creates a more "diffuse" sound. It feels like the room behind me got suddenly larger, which is great because I sit right in front of the wall. So there is a strange effect going on with opposite phase audio.

Comment: @Arsenal It’s not really all that ‘strange’ if you look at it scientifically. The destructive interference from the signals being out of phase results in attenuation, and if you’re in a proper surround setup and the rear channels are quieter than the rest, you’ll usually perceive the sounds as coming from further away, which in turn makes the ‘room’ (or alternatively ‘sound stage’) sound bigger than if physically is.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn the effect then would be the same as turning down the volume of the rear speakers. But it isn't.

Comment: @einpoklum - In addition to the other answers here, it will mess with the stereo image.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Exactly, "destructive interference when you are equally distant from both speakers". And what "equally distant" means depends on the wavelength. Your head is very much a point for anything below say 200 Hz (wavelengths of metres or more), so flipping the phase of one track leads to very dull and washed-out bass. This is why speaker terminals and cables are always color-coded, because connecting one speaker the wrong way round makes everything sound like a laptop.

Comment: At least on my version of Audacity (3.0, Windows) the *Nyquist Prompt* command is located under the *Tools* menu, not under *Effect*.

Answer (score 21):

An alternative, and in my opinion, easier way to calculate the difference between left and right track:

Click on the track, and then "Split Stereo Track"

[image: Split stereo track]

Click on the second track, and then "Effect/Invert"

[image: Effect Invert]

Set the panning of both tracks to center, select everything, and click on "Tracks/Mix/Mix and Render"

[image: Mix and render]

The result is the difference of both tracks. If it is zero, then it's the same track on the left and right sides. In this case, it's not.

[image: Result]

Comment: +1, but a slightly simpler approach is to use "Split Stereo to Mono", which automatically sets the pan to center so you don't need to manually do it afterwards.

Comment: To check for the possibility of opposite-phase, zoom in the time resolution so you can visually see the actual peaks and troughs of the two tracks.  It will be visually obvious if they're in phase or inverted.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a solution with [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net), which makes more sense for this task than ffmpeg, in my opinion.

Sox has the `oops` effect, aka karaoke filter:

> Out Of Phase Stereo effect.  Mixes stereo to twin-mono where each mono channel contains the difference between the left and right stereo channels.

And if both channels are the same, the result should be **all zero**.
We can use sox's `stat` effect to check this.

We can chain both effects and have one simple command:

```bsh
sox infile.wav -n oops stat
```

Which has this result for a "fake stereo" file, i.e. l/r channels are identical:

```
...
Maximum amplitude:     0.000000
Minimum amplitude:     0.000000 
...
```

For a file which is *almost stereo* it looks like this:

```
Maximum amplitude:     0.000397
```

In contrast, for a random song I picked:

```
Maximum amplitude:     0.950149
Minimum amplitude:    -1.000000
```

You could go even further and compare the channels at bit level, by `diff`ing the two channels:

```
# check the -b/-e params with: soxi in.wav
sox in.wav -b 16 -e signed -c 1 in.l.raw remix 1
sox in.wav -b 16 -e signed -c 1 in.r.raw remix 2
diff in.l.raw in.r.raw
```

Which will output

```
Binary files in.l.raw and in.r.raw differ
```

if they differ.

I'm sure you could also condense this into one line with subshells.

Comment: @theonlygusti if a GUI is OK, you can use Audacity: select all, Effect›Normalize…peak to 0.0 dB. The max amplitude will show up as a red line in the waveform (it actually marks clipping). Or use Analyze›Find Clipping.
If you need this on the CLI, I'm pulling a blank. I would probably write a tiny tool, e.g. using `audio2numpy` from a sibling answer here.

Comment: (I see the clipping indicator is not necessarily enabled. View›Show Clipping (on/off).)

Answer (score 9):

You can achieve this with FFmpeg, using the [pan](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pan-1) filter to generate the delta between both audio channels, followed by the [astats](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#astats-1) filter to print the overall RMS signal level.

```
ffmpeg -i $INPUT_FILE -filter:a "pan=1c|c0=c0-c1,astats=measure_perchannel=none:measure_overall=RMS_level" -f null /dev/null
```

Example output:

```
[Parsed_astats_1 @ 0x3ad1340] Channel: 1
[Parsed_astats_1 @ 0x3ad1340] Overall
[Parsed_astats_1 @ 0x3ad1340] RMS level dB: -16.015304
```

The lower the displayed RMS level the smaller is the difference between both audio channels. If they are perfectly equal the displayed value will be "-inf".

Comment: In some quick tests the RMS value of the Left-Right channel signal is around -18..-16dB. So maybe put the threshold at -30dB, or even lower? It basically is relative to the original input level. If the input file is already at -20dB the channel delta will also be much lower than in case the input file would have 0dB.

Comment: @einpoklum: If the file has been through lossy compression, that could have introduced differences that are just compression artifacts, if the compressor didn't notice and fully exploit the redundancy in the first place.  (e.g. by using a joint-stereo mode to compress sum or average and difference, instead of each channel separately.)  So you should generally listen to it to get some kind of idea what the difference sounds like.

Comment: @PeterCordes: If I know the file's provenance, I would probably know whether it's real stereo or not. But wav is barely ocmpressed...

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed `ffmpeg` and have `ffprobe`, use this command:

```
ffprobe -i file.wav -show_streams -select_streams a:0
```

This will give you an output where the important part is:

```
[STREAM]
...
channels=2
channel_layout=stereo
```

Note the `channels=2` and `channel_layout=stereo`, which you can pass through `grep`
to check.

A simpler command uses `-show_entries` to specify what you want, applies
print formatting via `-of` to strip everything else as well and sets verbosity to `0`
to not print the usual starting information:

```
ffprobe -i yourFile.mp4 -show_entries stream=channels -select_streams a:0 -of compact=p=0:nk=1 -v 0
```

This will return "2" for a typical stereo audio file.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47905308/165358)

---

For comparing the two channels, the post
[Comparing two supposedly identical tracks](https://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=82354)
has this advice that uses the free `Audacity`:

> Import them both into Audacity. Apply the "Invert" effect to one of the tracks. Select both tracks, then from the "Tracks menu > Mix and Render".
> If the tracks were identical, the result will be silence. To check that it is absolute silence, select the full (mix) track, and open the "Amplify" effect. If the Amplify effect says that the "New Peak Amplitude" is "-infinity", then the mix track is totally silent and the two imported files have identical audio.

The post contains much discussion that will interest you and some alternatives.

Comment: Won't it also show `channels=2` and `channel_layout=stereo` for two-channel mono being passed off as stereo?

Comment: @Mark: It's not an absolute measure, but it works for non-fake stereos.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly mathematical way: Calculate the Pearson correlation between left and right channels. If the result is very close to 1, the file is practically mono. If the result is -1, it is mono with one channel inverted.

How to do this with `scipy` and `audio2numpy` libraries:

```
import audio2numpy
from  scipy.stats import pearsonr
audio=audio2numpy.open_audio('filename')
pearsonr(audio[0][:,0], audio[0][:,1])
```

For a few stereo song files I picked at random the correlation between channels was varying between 0.6 and 0.9. For the one file downmixed to mono, converted back to stereo and encoded to joint stereo mp3 the correlation was 1 to 10 digits precision, and with the mono downmix panned towards right channel and same encoding, 4 digits precision.

Answer (score 0):

Extract each channel from stereo (or multichannel) wav as mono and in place without any temp files calculate md5.

```
ffmpeg -i stereo.wav -vn -af channelmap=channel_layout=mono:map=0 -f md5 -

ffmpeg -i stereo.wav -vn -af channelmap=channel_layout=mono:map=1 -f md5 -
```

you can also replace `-f md5 -` with file.wav and then compare them in Beyond Compare or other hex editor diff utility.

Answer (score -1):

If played on a true stereo player, the sound from the left speaker will be different than the right speaker, giving the allusion of real acoustic sound, as we aurally perceive it.